# How to scale border on a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I used borders to make 4 right triangles in the corners of the screen on divs. This is the link that I used to make this. http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/css/slopes

How can I scale this border based on window size? For example I want each triangle to take up 33% of the width and 25% of the height of the browser.

Would prefer if there is a solution in CSS or jQuery.

This is the link to a simplified version of my HTML and CSS. I shrunk the triangle to make them fit (on my site the triangles are 350px by 250px, so they need to be scaled down when window is resized). https://jsfiddle.net/9L5fkohr/`enter code here`

Comment: give these width and height you your div container

Comment: What? I don't understand.

Comment: post your html first

Comment: please take a look. I posted the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
#topLeftTriangle {
  font-size: 0px;
  line-height: 0%;
  width: 0px;
  border-top: 25vh solid #ceecec;
  border-right: 33vw solid transparent;
  float: left;
}
```

25vh = screen height

33vw = screen width

> REF: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Alos I added `body { margin: 0; }` to remove default margion from body.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#topRow {
  width: 100%;
}

.topRowElement {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
}

#topLeftTriangle {
  font-size: 0px;
  line-height: 0%;
  width: 0px;
  border-top: 25vh solid #ceecec;
  border-right: 33vw solid transparent;
  float: left;
}

#title {
  text-align: center;
}

#topRightTriangle {
  font-size: 0px;
  line-height: 0%;
  width: 0px;
  border-top: 25vh solid #ceecec;
  border-left: 33vw solid transparent;
  float: right;
}

.portalC {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.portal {
  text-align: center;
}

.botRowElement {
  display: inline;
  width: 33.33%;
}

#botRow {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

#botLeftTriangleC {
  font-size: 0px;
  line-height: 0%;
  width: 0px;
  border-bottom: 25vh solid #ceecec;
  border-right: 33vw solid transparent;
  float: left;
}

#botRightTriangleC {
  font-size: 0px;
  line-height: 0%;
  width: 0px;
  border-bottom: 25vh solid #ceecec;
  border-left: 33vw solid transparent;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="topRow">
      <div class="triangleC topRowElement" id="topLeftTriangleC">
        <div class="triangle" id="topLeftTriangle">
          triangle
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="topRowElement" id="titleC">
        <div id="title">
          Title
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="triangleC topRowElement" id="topRightTriangleC">
        <div class="triangle" id="topRightTriangle">
          triangle
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="main">
      <div id="portalMenu">
        <div class="portalC" id="docPortalC">
          <div class="portal" id="docPortal">
            Head1
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="portalC" id="pharmaPortalC">
          <div class="portal" id="pharmaPortal">
            Head2
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="botRow">
      <div class="triangleC botRowElement" id="botLeftTriangleC">
        <div class="triangle" id="botLeftTriangle">
          triangle
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="triangleC botRowElement" id="botRightTriangleC">
        <div class="triangle" id="botRightTriangle">
          triangle
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I didn't know about vh and vw. Would've helped a lot if I knew about this before.

Comment: Is there any way I can maintain the ratios of the triangle? Lets say the dimensions are 250px and 350px, can I maintain the ratio of the triangles regardless of how the browser is resized?

Comment: @harsh.gupta all using 25vh 33vh or 25vw 33vw

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much.